# One element inside <div> is much wider than the others while using flex. How can I make the separation even?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm learning how to create a website using flexbox and I'm having some trouble creating a header.

Basically, one `<a>` element that wraps around an `<img>` element takes up much more width than the other elements even though the picture itself isn't nearly as wide.

This is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x2fR.png

Here is my HTML code:

```
<body>
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="header">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="order.html">Order</a>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="./images/logo.svg" alt="logo"></a>
            <a href="#">Checkout</a>
            <a href="#">Contact us</a>
    </div>
    <div class="flowers-inventory">
        Flowers Inventory
    </div>
    <div class="tools-inventory">
        Tools Inventory
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
    *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-container{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.header{
    display: flex;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.header a{
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Roboto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgb(224, 170, 205);
}


.header img{
    width: 22%;
}

.header .logo{
    margin: 0 -40em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flex: 1 0 0;` in your flex-items (here: `.header a` selector)

```css
    *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-container{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.header{
    display: flex;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.header a{
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Roboto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    flex: 1 0 0;
    color: rgb(224, 170, 205);
}


.header img{
    width: 22%;
}

.header .logo{
    margin: 0 -40em;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="header">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="order.html">Order</a>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="https://cdn.clipart.email/2a1b0b49218f3d58c2b6df1630b609d9_free-rectangle-cliparts-download-free-clip-art-free-clip-art-on-_618-361.jpeg" alt="logo"></a>
            <a href="#">Checkout</a>
            <a href="#">Contact us</a>
    </div>
    <div class="flowers-inventory">
        Flowers Inventory
    </div>
    <div class="tools-inventory">
        Tools Inventory
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked great! Is there any way to make the separation between the elements smaller? Essentially, is it customisable?

Comment: Your welcome dear @Jamess11. I'm sure everything is possible with `CSS`. But If I get your meaning right, you need to change the `width` of `.header`. The margin of flex items will automatically change. for example in `.header` style: `width: 75%;`. If you need to preserve center align you can also add `margin: 0 auto` to `.header` selector.. feel free to ask again if this not helped.